# How to determine the nodes of a interpolating polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation, interpolation-theory

> Determine the nodes of the  first degree interpolating polynomial which approximate  $f(x) = cos(x)$ the best on $[-\pi,\pi]$ in the uniform norm. What is the interpolation error?

I think I need a polynomial such that $$p(-\pi)=-1, p(0)=1 $$
Further I get $$p[-\pi,0]=(1+1)/\pi=2/\pi$$
and $$p(x) = -1 +(x+\pi)2/\pi$$
So my nodes are $-\pi$ and $0$. Is that correct or am I wrong ?
The interpolation error is $$sin(z)(x+\pi)(x-\pi)x/6 \le (x^2-\pi^3)x/6 \le \pi^2/16 $$ with $x\in[-\pi,0]$  (where i chose $x=-\pi/2$).

Comment: It seems that you found some first trial function for the interval $[-π,0]$ while the task is  asking for a solution on $[-π,π]$.

Comment: The problem is that if I use $p(\pi)=-1$ and get $p[-\pi,0,\pi]$ then p would be a second degree polynomial and not a first degree polynomial

Comment: Compare your result to the zero polynomial. Look up the [Chebyshev alternation theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem) and the [Remez exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).